# Redirect url with Htaccess: match redirect parameter to specific position

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I am trying to do a permanent redirect of url from old website to new website.
From this

```
https://www.example.com/people/city/example-page-146128/guest-house-with-ac-rooms-6396
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/link-city-example_page-guest_house_with_ac_rooms--146128--6396.html
```

But my redirect seems not to be working. I have tried the following:

```
RewriteRule ^people\/(.*)\/(.*)-([0-9]+)\/(.*)-([0-9]+)$ /link-$1-$2-$4-$6-$3-$7-$5.html [R=301,NC,L]
```

but it redirects to different pages when there are hyphen in the slugs.
Is it possible to redirect to a specific position so that, irrespective of the number of hyphens, the last 3 parameters match what is specified?

Answer (score 0):

Try first replacing all the hyphens with underscores:

```
RewriteRule - _
RewriteRule ^people\/(.*)\/(.*)_([0-9]+)\/(.*)_([0-9]+)$ link-$1-$2-$4--$3--$5.html [R=301,NC,L]
```

I don't know exactly what `$6` and `$7` refer to.